# Select option from context click menu in Chrome

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, contextmenu, selenium-chromedriver

I'm facing an issue in Chrome 47, using Selenium (WebDriver) 2.48.2, ChromeDriver 2.20.353145, and Java as programming language. I couldn't find any solutions online. 
I need to open the "right click menu of browser" (or context click menu) from an input and I could do this using this code:

```
new Actions(driverExample).contextClick(inputExample).build().perform();
```

So the next step: select an option from it. I searched online and it seemed simple, but it's not. I didn't try on others browsers, but I always saw online that many people did this in Firefox and Internet Explorer using something like:

```
new Actions(driverExample).contextClick(inputExample).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_UP).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_UP).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN).build().perform();
```

In this situation I put two "arrow up" and one "enter", because I have to select the second option from the bottom. Anyway, this seems to work for people in Firefox and Internet Explorer, but not on Chrome and I also saw few discussions about this problem without solution. So why not give to me and the others a final solution here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm afraid no one here is going to fix Selenium for you. Have you tried opening an issue on their repo? (https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium)

Comment: Can you paste the logs or any debug information?

Comment: @TravelingTechGuy No, but I'm doing it now (thanks for the hint).

Comment: @MohitSharma If you explain me which and how, of course =D.

Answer (score 1):

Seems an issue. It is working with firefox but not with chromedriver. Please raise issue at https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/list

Sample Code:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();      
driver.get("http://www.google.com/");
Actions a = new Actions(driver);

WebElement input = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
input.sendKeys("test");
a.contextClick(input).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.ARROW_UP,Keys.ARROW_UP,Keys.ARROW_UP,Keys.ARROW_UP,Keys.ENTER)).build().perform();
```

Comment: Before creating a new one, I searched and found this.
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1003&q=context&colspec=ID%20Status%20Pri%20Owner%20Summary